org-publish how to add relative path to css file
I would like to add same css file to published html files.
But my posts are in nested directories like below:
├── posts
│       ├── 01-post.org
│       └── other-posts
            └── 02-post.org

So the path to the CSS file would be different for each of the files.
I found org-publish-project-alist :html-head but it takes hardcoded string.
